# what is yolo_best.weights file? How is it different from yolo_custom.weights

Tags: python, python-3.x, object-detection, yolo

I'm training a custom model on Yolo v4 for object detection, I know that Yolo saves "**yolo_custom.weights**" file every 100 iterations and "**yolo_custom_XXXX.weights**" every 1000 iterations.

Other than that, I've got a new file named "**yolo_custom_best.weights**" file and it keeps updating like "**yolo_custom.weights**" file some number of iterations.

I'm training my model using darknet with following command:
`./darknet detector train "data/obj.data" "cfg/yolov4_custom.cfg" yolov4.conv.137 -dont_show -map`

I've used the `-map` flag for first time while training now.

My questions are:

1. What is the "**yolo_custom_best.weights**" file? and is it formed because of me using `-map` flag? Is it better to detect using that file than the"**yolo_custom.weights**" file?
2. If I want to resume training from a certain point (if my Google Colab Runtime ends), which file should I use to resume? `custom` or `custom_best`?
3. Can some one explain me actually what is mAP? and is it causing this file to generate and update?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

1. The 'best weights' file is formed when using the -map flag.
2. When your Colab run time gets disconnected I would say its best to resume training from the `yolo_last.weights` file. This can be done by :

```py
!./darknet detector train data/obj.data cfg/yolov4-obj.cfg yolov4-obj_last.weights -dont_show
```

This pickups training from where it was last updated.

3. mAP (mean average precision) is the average of AP (average precision) over all categories (I could be wrong here). [Here is a useful link to explain mAP](https://medium.com/@jonathan_hui/map-mean-average-precision-for-object-detection-45c121a31173).

Answer (score 0):

1. Your Yolo best weights file will save the weights of best-known map accuracy and loss
2. you should use the custom file for resuming your results.
   [image: To restart your training]

[[image: my weights2]

MAP accuracy is mean average precision
Check out this link for clearing your doubts [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/map-mean-average-precision-might-confuse-you-5956f1bfa9e2)